# Why is my xpath matching an undesired element?

Tags: xpath

I am trying to locate elements with the class "foo"

```
<div id="foo1">
<div id = "foo2">
<div class = "foo">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my xpath:

```
/div/div/div[contains(@class,'foo')]
```

And this is the code it's finding:

```
<div id="foo1">
<div id = "foo2">
<div class = "foo-err">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The path is returning the div class = "foo-err" element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`contains()` is a substring match. It's basically saying "if 'foo' is **ANYWHERE** in the class attribute, match the element".

If you want an exact match, then try

```
[@class='foo']
```

Comment: Would the xpath then be : /div/div/div[@class='foo']

Comment: The moral of the tale: don't assume you can guess what a function does from its name alone.

Comment: @MichaelKay Actually, the moral of the tale is "_the function's name probably describes exactly what it does_". :-)

Comment: Yeah once finding out what it does I did think ah of course...contains

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match `foo` in a list of classes but not `foo-err`, you need a more-complex construct: `[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' foo ')]`, which will look for foo surrounded by spaces in the full class string also surrounded by spaces.  Thus `'foo bar'` -> `' foo bar '` -> contains `' foo '`, but `'foobaz bar'` -> `' foobaz bar '` -> does not contain `' foo '`.